# how to do Locking a control on a data repeater?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How do lock a control within a "data repeater" so that i prevent users from editing data in that control. I do not want to use the "enabled" property  as it "grey out" the control and I have set the background of each control to  some color depending on the value of the control.

I have tried setting the "locked" property to true in the "properties page" during design of the form but this doesn't seem to work as the control is still editable.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set enabled = false cover the control with a transparent div with higher z-index. So if the user clicks on the control it actually gets clicked on the div sitting on top of it.